# Why group name "docker" is not created on installation of docker on mac?

Tags: docker, docker-ce

After running:

```
  brew cask install docker
```

UNIX socket file is not part of `docker` group in my mac laptop(docker host)

```
$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  daemon  70 12 Jan 08:19 /var/run/docker.sock -> /Users/user1/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.sock
```

---

because `docker` group is not created

```
 $ cat /etc/group | grep docker
 $ uname -a
Darwin user1 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Sun Dec  1 18:59:03 PST 2019; root:xnu-4903.278.19~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

 $
 $ cat /etc/group | grep daemon
 daemon:*:1:root
```

---

On ubuntu `docker` group name gets created, after installation of docker

Running jenkins docker container(as [DIND](https://itnext.io/docker-in-docker-521958d34efd)), but cannot perform `usermod -aG docker jenkins` within Dockerfile.

Goal is to run docker client within jenkins container that can talk to docker daemon running on docker host, through UNIX socket file(`/var/run/docker.sock`).

---

Why installation of docker on mac does not create `docker` group?

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked that the _numeric_ group IDs match?  Are you running Docker-in-Docker, or trying to reuse the host Docker socket?  What specific commands are you running and what specific errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Docker for Mac is just special like that. You can solve it few ways:

From **least** recommended to **most** recommended order:

1. Modify the permission of /var/run/docker.sock so that other groups can access the socket.
2. Give sudo access to the jenkins user
3. Use `socat` to expose the daemon on tcp socket instead.

From https://www.benjaminpack.com/blog/docker-jenkins-mac/

The socat process wraps /var/run/docker.sock on the host by way of a mounted volume and exposes it in a bi-directional fashion as a TCP server to Jenkins. All without giving Jenkins more permissions than it needs.

Comment: modify the permission of `/var/run/docker.sock` to which other group, on host? `groupadd -g 1000 docker` does not work on mac

Comment: I meant something like `chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock`. Again I do not recommend this unless you are doing it just for experimentation.

Comment: This is the problem, I see for mounting folders